# unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 xxx when installing gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently writing a gem, which for reasons needs to include a full copy of WordPress(Not entirely sure if that's relevant).
Now, problem; running a gem build goes fine, but gem install give this error message for what seems to be for every binary file(.gif,.png etc.), And after some number of errorr, the process halts.

```
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 xxx/xxx.xx
```

the 'x89' identifier is different for some of the messages.

Here is a sample

```
unable to convert "\xF2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/spinner.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/stars-2x.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/stars.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/w-logo-blue.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/w-logo-white.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/wheel.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/wpspin_light-2x.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/wpspin_light.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/xit-2x.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/xit.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-admin/images/yes.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet/_inc/img/logo-full-2x.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xE8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/Genericons.eot, skipping
unable to convert "\xFC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/Genericons.woff, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/screenshot.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/genericons/Genericons-Regular.otf, skipping
```

The last line I get before the process halts is

```
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/templates/wordpress/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/bigplay.png, skipping
```

I'v seen similar questions other places, but they have all been for a specific gem when trying to install it.
What I'm asking is how I can fix my gem so this error is not produced?

Here is my gemspec

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + '/lib/gemname.rb'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'gemname'
  s.version     = Gemname::VERSION
  s.executables << 'gemname'
  s.licenses    = ['LICENSE']
  s.summary     = "Short description"
  s.description = "Long description"
  s.authors     = ["Sigurd Berg Svela"]
  s.email       = 'sigurdbergsvela@gmail.com'
  s.files       = `git ls-files -- lib/*`.split("\n")
  s.homepage    = 'https://github.com/sigurdsvela/gemname'
  s.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.0.0'

  gemRootDir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

  # get an array of submodule dirs by executing 'pwd' inside each submodule
  `git submodule --quiet foreach pwd`.split("\n").each do |submodule_path|

    # for each submodule, change working directory to that submodule
    Dir.chdir(submodule_path) do

      # issue git ls-files in submodule's directory
      submodule_files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")

      # prepend the submodule path to create absolute file paths
      submodule_files_fullpaths = submodule_files.map do |filename|
        "#{submodule_path}/#{filename}"
      end

      # remove leading path parts to get paths relative to the gem's root dir
      # (this assumes, that the gemspec resides in the gem's root dir)
      submodule_files_paths = submodule_files_fullpaths.map do |filename|
        filename.gsub "#{gemRootDir}/", ""
      end

      # add relative paths to gem.files
      s.files += submodule_files_paths
    end

  end

  # Hardcode include gitignores submodule
  Dir.chdir(Boot.dir + "/templates/gitignores") do
    submodule_path = Boot.dir + "/templates/gitignores"

    # issue git ls-files in submodule's directory
    submodule_files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")

    # prepend the submodule path to create absolute file paths
    submodule_files_fullpaths = submodule_files.map do |filename|
      "#{submodule_path}/#{filename}"
    end

    # remove leading path parts to get paths relative to the gem's root dir
    # (this assumes, that the gemspec resides in the gem's root dir)
    submodule_files_paths = submodule_files_fullpaths.map do |filename|
      filename.gsub "#{gemRootDir}/", ""
    end

    # add relative paths to gem.files
    s.files += submodule_files_paths
  end

end
```

Comment: Show us your `gemspec`.

Comment: `gem install YOUR_GEM_NAME --no-document` should suppress those error messages. Actually, it was a successful, albeit noisy, installation. It looks like `gem` tries to extract documentation from binary files.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, the process halted after some number of errors, which all where "unable to convert...". But --no-document worked. Still curious though as to why it halted.

Comment: My guess would be you should file an issue to `rubygems` maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the gem installer.
But 'gem install germane **--no-document**' works as a temporary solution.